# Ionization energy meaning in terms of Bohr model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, electrons, atomic-physics

Ionization energy means the energy required to remove an electron from the valence shell of an atom. Now Bohr did believe in orbits, so what does ionization energy mean in the Bohr model?

I understand that an electron becomes a free electron after ionization (i.e. that it has to be completely removed). But I don't understand *which* state the electron requires energy to jump to from the ground state.

Finally, does separation energy and ionization energy mean the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This link](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Bohr.html) may help.

[image: bohrorb]

The correct quantum mechanical solutions and the Bohr model solutions coinside, energy levels as calculated are the same.

To get ionisation the electron must go to n=infinty, and in order not to be trapped back radiating a photon needs some extra energy and momentum. So ionisation is an interaction between a charged particle hitting the electron and extracting it from its energy level. ( as in the [photoelectric effect](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod2.html), the electorn leaves and the atom is ionized)

> Finally, does separation energy and ionization energy mean the same thing?

Separation energy might mean [breaking chemical bonds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_bond), not necessarily ionizing the atoms.

> A chemical bond is a lasting attraction between atoms, ions or molecules that enables the formation of chemical compounds